# how to find ´ char occurrences using grep command and spanish keyboard through ssh

Tags: linux, parsing, grep

does anybody know how to find ocurrences of the character ´ on  a text file using grep? I tried the following on a ssh connection:

```
user@server:~$cat > myfile
´´´sometext
´´s´more
end´
```

and then:

`grep ´ myfile` and also `grep \´ myfile` and `grep '´' myfile` and `grep '\´' myfile` and `grep "´" myfile` and `grep "\´" myfile`

but neither of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep \´ myfile` will work. If that doesn't work its not `´` character.

See my console log,

```
$ cat myfile -n
 1  `
 2  `
 3  ´ 
 4  ´ `
 5  `quoted´ 
 6
 7  `3l2l4kj3
 8  echo ` `
 9  hello
10  done

$ grep \´  myfile -n
3:´ 
4:´ `
5:`quoted´
```

Comment: I also tried creating a file using cat and then grep it: For some reason it does not work either. I'm shocked it works for you and not for me. What could be the reason? (I'm through ssh connection, by the way)

Comment: Another funny thing: there's no problem recognizing `, only ´ is giving me trouble

Comment: I'm thinking it could be my keyboard is spanish. When I press that key it doesn't show on the screen until I press another key, but I don't know how to fix that or write it in another way...

Comment: You were right, it was NOT the character I was writing to the file, but some rubbish putty sends instead (and interprets like it too when reading the file). So the problem was not SSH but putty client: When I switched to ssh over cygwin I could se a bunch of binary non text rubbish instead of the actual character, which explains why the grep command didn't work even when querying the same rubbish.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep '´' myfile
```

Double quotes would prob also work ...

Comment: Then that's not the character in your file.

Comment: how is it posible if I create a file on the same command line using cat > myfile and pressing the same key?

Comment: (and when I check the file with cat myfile, of course the ´ are there...)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try 
`grep -e "´" myfile`?

At least

> echo -e "some text with ´\nsome text without it\nagain some text with
>   ´\nagain some text without it" | grep -e "´"

gives

> some text with ´
>  again some text with ´

http://ideone.com/xEKdC

Comment: [Double quotes wont work here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/bashref/DoubleQuotes.html)

Comment: You are right, I though it was `\`` not `´`. `´` is not a special character.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '´' myfile
```

I tried, and it works.

````
[root@s1 ~]# cat myfile
```sometext
``s`more
end`
[root@s1 ~]# grep '`' myfile
```sometext
``s`more
end`
````

Comment: Could it be something related to the fact I'm using an spanish distribution keyboard?